# XML Schema for a mixed content complexType containing non-empty strings and elements

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I'm trying to create an XML Schema to validate the following xml structure.

```
<ul>
    <li>123
        <ul>
            <li>A</li>
            <li>B</li>
            <li>C</li>
        </ul>
    </li>  
</ul>
```

I would like it to fail if the "123" text content is missing or is only white space.

The following schema is as far as I have got.  It insists on exactly 3 non-empty list elements.

```
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="ul">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="li">
          <xs:complexType mixed="true">
            <xs:sequence>
              <xs:element name="ul">
                <xs:complexType>
                  <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element type="nonEmptyString" name="li" maxOccurs="3" minOccurs="3" />
                  </xs:sequence>
                </xs:complexType>
              </xs:element>
            </xs:sequence>
          </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:simpleType name="nonEmptyString">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:minLength value="1"/>
            <xs:pattern value="(\s*[^\s]\s*)+"></xs:pattern>
        </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>    
</xs:schema>
```

I'm guessing from [In XML Schema, can mixed content restrict the type of the text?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979159/in-xml-schema-can-mixed-content-restrict-the-type-of-the-text) that this probably isn't possible but I thought I would ask anyway in case there was a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

If you want only letters lower or upper case change

```
<xs:pattern value="(\s*[^\s]\s*)+"></xs:pattern>
```

in

```
<xs:pattern value="([a-zA-Z]*)"/>
```