# How to define an XSD mixed complexType required to be non-empty?

Tags: xml, xsd

I am creating an XSD schema and I need to define complexType elements that are mixed (have both text and elements) but I need to require these to be non-empty. For simpleType there is minLength but I don't know how to (or if it is possible) to restrict this for a mixed complexType.

To illustrate the need, take the following examples in which there is a 'text' root element and the mixed complexType is 'name':

```
"<text></text>"  <= Valid
"<text>His name was <name>John <unk/> Mal<del>c</del>kovich</name>.</text>"  <= Valid
"<text>His name was <name>John Malkovich</name>.</text>"  <= Valid
"<text>A person called <name></name> was outside.</text>"  <= Invalid
```

Right now I have the following schema which gives valid to the last example, but I need it to be invalid. How can TextType be required to be non-empty?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" elementFormDefault="qualified">

  <!--==============-->
  <!-- ROOT ELEMENT -->
  <!--==============-->
  <xs:element name="text">
    <xs:complexType mixed="true">
      <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:group ref="TextTypeChoice"/>
        <xs:element name="name" type="NameType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      </xs:choice>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>

  <!--==============================-->
  <!-- Group for Text type elements -->
  <!--==============================-->
  <xs:group name="TextTypeChoice">
    <xs:choice>
      <xs:element name="unk" type="EmptyType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xs:element name="del" type="RawTextType" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:group>

  <!--=============================-->
  <!-- Definition of the Text type -->
  <!--=============================-->
  <xs:complexType name="TextType" mixed="true">
    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:group ref="TextTypeChoice"/>
    </xs:choice>
  </xs:complexType><!--TextType-->

  <!--=============================-->
  <!-- Definition of the Name type -->
  <!--=============================-->
  <xs:complexType name="NameType">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:extension base="TextType"/>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType><!--NameType-->

  <!--===================-->
  <!-- Type for raw text -->
  <!--===================-->
  <xs:simpleType name="RawTextType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
      <xs:minLength value="1"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType><!--RawTextType-->

  <!--========================================-->
  <!-- Type for empty / self-closing elements -->
  <!--========================================-->
  <xs:simpleType name="EmptyType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:maxLength value="0"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType><!--EmptyType-->

</xs:schema>
```

Comment: Could you not just require the elements such as `name` to be non-empty?

Comment: @kjhughes name is a NameType which I need it to be a mixed complexType. Precisely the problem is I don't know how to restrict the text of a mixed complexType.

Comment: So, you'd like `NameType` elements to be mixed recursively, and they can be empty, but they cannot contain other *empty* `NameType` elements?

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that what I want is not possible. There is no "control over the child text nodes whose values cannot be constrained at all" (https://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/xml/schema/ch07_05.htm) for mixed complexTypes. Furthermore, this question might be considered a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7979159/in-xml-schema-can-mixed-content-restrict-the-type-of-the-text

Answer (score 0):

### Options

1. In **XSD 1.0**, you can support your model, if I understand it correctly, by making some adjustments:

   - Have a separate type for the `text` root element whose content model
     allows it to have mixed content, possibly empty, that includes
     `name`, `del`, and `unk`.
   - Globally (not just within `text`) disallow `name`, `del`, and `unk` from being empty.
2. In **XSD 1.1**, you can support your model via assertions that can force different constraints to occur within `text` than exist globally:

   ```
   <xs:assert test="every $e in .//* satisfies $e != ''"/>
   ```

Comment: These answers are not enough for me to understand know how to define the schema with the described requirements. Maybe can you post an XSD either in 1.0 or 1.1 such that the examples in the question validate as required?